# iPad Retina Images CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a set of images with 2048 by 1496 size, which I am using only for iPad Retina display. My website is targeted only for iPad Retina so I dont have to worry about down sampling or anything else for now. I have just created web pages only for retina display.

I have the css and html specifying the images ( as background images ). But when I see the page on Retina, its not visible completely, its partly visible.

Why is this when images are actually 2048 by 1496 px? Is there any setting to be done.

Comment: If you see your website in safari or google chrome in iPad you should know browser toolbar eats space

Comment: How much is visible?  Is it most of the image?  Half of the image?

Comment: @ Brad, Yes I have set the viewport. <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> @NickD, Its not even half, only some part is visible

Comment: Would it be helpful to show the css and/or html?

Comment: I think the pixels of the display are not the same as the actual pixel size of the background image.  Try using a 1024 x 748 image, you are probably seeing the top left quadrant of the image.  I have read some other posts here and via Google that explain the pixel density and how it applies in this case.

Comment: It worked when I added a wrapper with exact width and height, but now I have a simple html page with just one image, it is not displayed. The image size is 2048 by 2744 . It shows a white blank page! Something like this,<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name = "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content = "yes" /> 

<title>IOS</title>


<!-- Styles -->

<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
<link href="css/styleiPad4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />

</head>

<body>

<img src="Images/Retina/Test.png">

</body>
</html>

Comment: Your image resolution is correct as per iPad Ratina resolution. But can you check it with jQuery to conform? try to alert $(document).height() and $(document).width(). It will make sure how much pixels resolution really its rendering for web.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried setting the "background-size" property on the elements that have the large, retina images as backgrounds?

It would look something like this:

```
#retinaImage {
 background: url(images/huge-retina-image.jpg) no-repeat;
 width: 1024px;
 height: 768px;
 background-size: 1024px 768px;
}
```

The iPad's resolution is 2048x1536, but it is still 1024x768 in "CSS pixels" - it's just that each of these CSS pixels contain 4 device pixels.  Conceptually it can be hard to wrap your head around this.  Here's an article that might help:

[Towards a Retina Web (Smashing Magazine)](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/)

Comment: It's a nice article in Smashing Magazine(my favorite). Clear all my doubts. Thanks for sharing Chris :)

Answer (score 1):

Read the article share by Chris ([Towards A Retina Web](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/)). You not need to use 2048 by 2744. 1024 X 768 resolution image is enough. Ipad Ratina display will handle its resolution automatically.

Use 1024 X 768 resolution. You'll automatically get better display image in small file size. Not need to use background size in CSS.

Comment: If you want to serve retina images, you must use real 2048x1536 - the iPad will upscale smaller images but the quality will suffer.

Comment: In that case check your browser resolution with jQuery. $(document).height() and $(document).width(). If it'll return 1024 width and 768 height then you don't have any other option. About upscale you are right quality will suffer because any application can try for it but can't give you 100% result. About image quality, it's the way iPad work so we can't do anything :(. But your image quality will look good in 1024 X 768 too because in iPad density of pixels is very high, so you image not look like scaled or pixelated.

Comment: You do have another option - specify a 2048x1536 image as the background, then set background-size to 1024x768. Then the image will retain full quality and be fully visible.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert In that case your image will always look like same as 1024 X 768. The difference is it'll take long time to load. Because it's iPad technology to add pixels in display. CSS can't to anything for it.

Comment: @Tarun - you're misunderstanding how iPads work. If you scale an image to 1024 on the iPad it will still render at 2048px resolution if the source image is 2048. This is because an iPad uses a false resolution of 1024 for the purposes of laying out pages. Telling Safari the image should be rendered 1024 pixels wide does NOT downsample the original image to 1024px.

Comment: Indeed, there is a difference between "virtual pixels" (1024) and actual pixels (2048). This is the "device pixel ratio" found under window.devicePixelRatio. For retina devices, this is 2. For each "virtual" pixel in the layout, there are 2 physical pixels.